# Instagram like filters in a phonegap application using JavaScript

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am about to build a phonegap application and was wanting to build a function, a little but like how you can add filters on your photos like you can On instagram

Il tried to find how it's done with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas on the technique or if it's even possible without objective c?

Andrew

Comment: do you have the source code to demonstrate the answer to this question as the link has been removed?

Comment: Hi sorry, I didnt build the app in the end. Made a prototype for a possible client but in the end the budget wasnt up to the amount of work. sorry. there is a net tuts tutorial on using php to build instagram filters/effects. might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem wound up creating a new phonegap plugin to accomplish the task!

Basically how it works in theory is to capture the image with phonegap and pass the new image's URI to objective-c to edit. Using the CoreImage Framework you can apply and edit the photo then save it back and pass a new url back to your app.

Check out this blog post and git project!

hope this helps!

https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter
http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=138

Comment: glad you dig - planning on expanding on it to make it a bit easier to use as a true plugin - but until then this will work :P

Comment: So can we run the app on an Android device too ? because you say 'pass the new image's URI to **objective-c** to edit.'. I am a newbie, so could someone explain this to me

Comment: Check out the github project both iOS and Android are together - there is a java and objective-c version that will allow you to use the plugin for both devices

Comment: Do you still have a link to this as it seems to have been removed?

Comment: This is an awesome plugin, just one question. How do I save the new image created?